# How does git differentiate between deleted branches and new, unpushed local branches?

Tags: git, branch

Is it possible to prune all branches deleted from the remote on my local checkout while leaving my unpushed, local branches intact? How does branch deletion from the remote propagate to clones and forks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You probably want to set `fetch.prune`, and then just avoid creating any branch names that you don't intend to use.  Use the remote-tracking names (`refs/remotes/origin/*` names) to view other people's commits.

#### Long

There are really several different questions embedded in here, so let's take them one at a time:

> How does git differentiate between deleted branches and new, unpushed local branches?

It doesn't, but it doesn't really *need* to.

> Is it possible to prune all branches deleted from the remote on my local checkout while leaving my unpushed, local branches intact?

Maybe, depending on what you mean.

> How does branch deletion from the remote propagate to clones and forks?

It doesn't.

All of these questions stem from what I consider to be a sort of [category error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_mistake): you are thinking of branches as if they *matter*.   More precisely, you're thinking of *branch names* as global and shared—but they're not.

#### Commits

Git is really all about *commits*.

- Each commit is numbered, and these *numbers* are shared globally: every Git computes them the same way.  The actual computation—and hence the reason that commit hash IDs are so big and ugly—is a cryptographic checksum of the complete contents of the internal Git object (the checksum is of the uncompressed data, though objects are always stored in some compressed form).
- Each commit consists of two parts.  The main data in a commit contain a full snapshot of every file that Git knew about, at the time whoever made the commit, made that commit.  The *metadata* in a commit contain information about the commit: who made it and when, a log message, and—crucially for Git itself—the commit number, or hash ID, of the immediately previous commit, which Git calls the *parent* of that commit.  (Merge commits are distinguished by having two or more parents.)
- This numbering system means that as long as you know the hash ID of the *last* commit in some chain, Git can use this to work *backwards* from the last commit to every earlier commit.  (It also has some consequences that are surprising to those familiar with most other version control systems, such as: many commits are on multiple branches simultaneously, and the set of branches that contain a commit changes dynamically.)

#### Names, including branch names

This leads to what branch names do for Git (and us): they simply remember the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain. We can draw this like so:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--name
```

The name allows Git to quickly find the hash ID for the last commit `H`.  The metadata in `H` includes the hash ID of earlier commit `G`, which allows Git to find `G`.  Commit `G` includes the has ID of earlier commit `F`, and so on.

Tag names and other Git names do the same kind of thing: each name, which in general has the form `refs/group/name`, maps to one hash ID.  The *`group`* here is `heads` for branch names, `tags` for tag names, and includes `remotes` for remote-tracking names, which we'll get to in a moment.  When and whether to do this *start with the named commit, then work backwards* is up to each Git command: `git log`, for instance, almost always does it, while `git rev-parse`, for instance, doesn't.

Each repository thus consists of two [key-value databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database):

- The main one, which is duplicated by cloning, has hash IDs as keys, with internal Git objects as the values.  The keys are just checksums of the values, which provides a consistency check: when Git looks up the value, it computes the checksum, which must match the key it used to look up the value.
- The secondary database is *not* (necessarily) duplicated; it maps from names to hash IDs.

#### Cloning, fetching, and remote-tracking names

When you use `git clone` to copy a Git repository, your Git fetches the commits from some other Git.  Your Git has their Git *find* the commits to fetch using their branch names.  Your Git knows whether you have any of those commits yet using their hash IDs, though of course `git clone` starts by making an empty repository.  A later `git fetch` does the same fetching that `git clone` does, but this time you probably do have some of the commits.

You can, at any time, run `git ls-remote origin` for instance to see the list of names-and-hash-IDs that a `git fetch origin` will see.  (Try it out some time; it's a read-only operation.)  This is actually just the first step of `git fetch`, which does this same operation to get information about what they have, before it starts the commit-copying process.

Having fetched new-to-your-Git commits—either as the middle part of `git clone`, or using `git fetch`—your Git now takes its knowledge of their branch names and hash IDs, and other names, and uses this to create or update *your* Git's names.  For each *branch* name `refs/heads/B` here, your Git changes the name to read `refs/remotes/remote/B`, where *`remote`* is the name you are using to talk to the other Git.  For `git clone` this would normally be `origin` (though you can set it); after `git remote add`, which lets you choose a name, you would run `git fetch` with the name you chose.

So, assuming you're using the remote name `origin`, this turns their `refs/heads/master` into your `refs/remotes/origin/master`, and turns their `refs/heads/dev` into your `refs/remotes/origin/dev`.  Because these names begin with `refs/remotes`, they are *remote-tracking names*, not branch names.  Your Git creates or updates each of these names based on all the branch names it saw.<sup>1</sup>  So you end up with a remote-tracking name for each branch name that your Git saw.

The *last* step of your own `git clone` is to run `git checkout`.<sup>2</sup>  This will, in general, create one branch name in your new repository.  The `checkout` (or in Git 2.23 and later, `switch`) command has a special feature in which, if you name a branch but don't actually *have* that branch name, they *create* the name using a corresponding remote-tracking name.  Since your Git just created all the remote-tracking names, you will have exactly one correct corresponding name here, and your Git will create that one, pointing to the same commit as the branch name from which your remote-tracking name was derived.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a general requirement on *all* references—these `refs/*` names are references—that they must point to some existing, valid Git object in your repository.  Branch and remote-tracking names are further constrained to point only to *commit* objects, while tag names can point to any of the four internal object types.  You can direct `git fetch` to fetch only some subset of commits, and if that's the case, your `git fetch` will be unable to create or update a name that would now point to an object that you don't actually have.  It just skips these as needed.

<sup>2</sup>Or `git switch`, but in fact, this is all built in to `git clone` directly, so it just uses the code, not the front end interface.  You can also use `git clone --no-checkout` to skip this step.

<sup>3</sup>You can defeat this in several ways.  Of course the simplest is the `--no-checkout` option mentioned in footnote 2, but you can also clone a repository that has no branch names, or use a tag name with the `-b` option to `git clone`.  We don't really need to cover what happens in these cases here, but it's supposed to be unsurprising, once you know the underlying mechanisms.

---

#### Mirror clones and GitHub-style forks

You can also run `git clone --bare`, which we won't cover properly here, or `git clone --mirror`; and GitHub and other hosting services offer the option of "forking" a repository, which is a lot like using `git clone --mirror`, only different and with some extra features that we also won't cover here.

A *bare* clone is simply a clone without a working tree.  The files inside commits are all frozen and read-only, and it's not possible to actually do any new work on them, so with a regular clone, you get a working tree, where you have files you *can* see, read, write, and otherwise use to get work done.  A bare clone omits this.  The purpose of omitting a work area is so that the bare clone can receive `git push` operations safely.  In a non-bare clone, a push operation could, if Git allowed it, disconnect the ongoing work from the branch (for reasons we won't really be able to cover properly here to keep the answer shorter).

A *mirror* clone is a bare clone in which, instead of creating remote-tracking names, Git copies all the branch names as-is.  That is, if the source repository had a `refs/heads/dev`, the clone also has a `refs/heads/dev`.  This mirroring state is recorded, so that a subsequent `git fetch` in the mirror clone *replaces* its previous branch-to-hash-ID mappings with the new ones from the other Git.  This means it's not only impossible to do any new work in the mirror clone, it's also often a bad idea to `git push` *to* the mirror clone, because things pushed to it will be lost by the next `git fetch`.

A GitHub or other hosing service *fork* uses what might as well be a mirror clone to make the initial copy: the new clone has the same set of branch names as the original clone, and is bare so that it can receive push operations.  But this forked copy never has `git fetch` run *in* it, so it is safe to run `git push` *to* it.  (The hosting server also sets up some outside-of-Git-itself linkages so that you can make pull requests.  These kinds of pull requests are not Git features: they're implemented on the hosting server, and each one has its own different quirks.)

#### Deleting branch names and `fetch.prune`

Now that we know that branch names themselves are local to each repository, we can see how deleting a branch name works.  We might start out with, e.g.:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- dev
```

We use some Git operation to make the name `master` point to commit `J`, so that all commits up through `J` are now on *both* branches:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- dev, master
```

and now we don't need the *name* `dev` any more, so we delete it:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- master
```

That's all there really is to it, at least, *locally*.

But what about some other Git that copied our `refs/heads/dev` to their `refs/remotes/origin/dev`?  Now that our `dev` is done, their `origin/dev` ... well, by default, sticks around.  This is probably the wrong default, but it's what Git did originally.

Suppose *we* are the guy with the `origin/dev`.  We have, in our Git:

```
          K   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/dev
```

We don't need a `dev` so we don't create it; we created `feature` and made commit `K` on it.  But now `origin`'s `dev` is gone.  One thing we can do about this is run:

```
git fetch --prune
```

or, more conveniently, configure `fetch.prune` to `true` (in this repository or globally in our per-user Git configuration, using `git config --global`).  This tells our Git: *when I run `git fetch`, act as if I ran `git fetch --prune`*, which tells our Git: *when you've gotten a listing of all of their branches, use that listing to* remove *any `refs/remotes/origin/*` name that does not have a corresponding branch name on the other Git* (substitute in the appropriate remote if it is not `origin`).

What we end up with locally is this:

```
          K   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- origin/master
```

Since we never created a local `dev`, we don't have to delete a local `dev`.  We just have our `master` out of date.  If we don't *like* having an out of date `master`, we can just delete our name `master`.  We don't need it any more: we have our `feature` that we're working on, and that's the one name we *do* need, to record our unpushed commits.

#### Recap

The key to understanding all of this is that we don't need to care about unpushed *branches*.  We need to care about unpushed *commits*.  Our branch names, in our repositories, are there to keep track of the *last* commit: that's what a branch name does for us.  When we are "on" some branch—in that `git status` says `on branch whatever`—and run `git commit`, the new commit will get a new unique number, and then Git will *automatically update that branch name* so that it records the new commit's hash-ID number, instead of the old branch-tip.

If and when we go to `git push` some commits to some other Git repository, we will:

- have our Git send the commits to their Git, by their hash IDs; then
- have our Git ask their Git to set one of *their* branch names to record the *last* of those commits.

That last step can create or update a branch in some other Git, and for sanity's sake we usually like to use the same name in each Git.  But it's not actually *required*.  The part that is shared is the commit itself, with its unique hash ID.  They have their own branch names, and we have our own.  We copy their branch names to our remote-tracking names, so that we can find any commits that they have for which we don't have a *branch* name, but until we want to make new commits of our own, we don't need any branch names.

Comment: There's a lot to digest in this answer. Thanks for taking the time to write this up, I'll be reading through it at least a few times over the next week!